# Adding JSON to a List in my Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, post

I have seen a lot of posts that seem to somewhat address my situation but they all leave me a bit confused.

I have an object that I am `POST`ing to my Controller. I have the post coming to my controller okay by doing this:

```
$('#fileSubmit').click(function () {
    var filesObj = [];

    $('#fileList .files .fileName').each(function () {
        var name = $(this).text();
        filesObj.push({ 'name': name });
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/FileUpload/ImportCommit",
        data: filesObj,
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

I want to then take that JSON object and put it into a list in my controller. So far here is what i have, but I have not done a lot of coding in C# and don't know what to do next.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ImportCommit(List<string> filenames)
{

}
```

I know my controller method's code is blank, but am not sure what to do next. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what's blank?  the filenames parameter or your controller method's code?

Comment: Sorry - controller method's code is blank.

Comment: So if filenames has values you're done no?  filenames is already of type list, the <string> is the type of listitem on that list.  I take filesObj is just a JSON string of filenames with no properties or attributes.  To work on your list just manipulate filenames.

Comment: Sorry... `filenames` is also null.

Comment: Ok, no problem, basically the model of the values you post & the model the controller is expecting have to be one for one.  I take it because you can tell filenames is null, the controller code is firing off the jquery.  So,... what happens when you change filesObj.push({ 'name': name }); to filesObj.push({ name }); ?

Comment: I changed `filesObj.push(name);` and it returns `["delete-icon.png", "something.exe", "anotherthng.exe"]` when I had it log to the console, but `filenames` is still null.

Comment: the return looks good, the JSON format looks a little bit shaky though.  I think if you follow the answer below & do like data: JSON.Stringify(filesObj) that'll give a JSON string that should populate filenames.

Comment: i am getting a format like this: `[{"name":"delete-icon.png"},{"name":"anothersomething.exe"},{"name":"something.exe"}]` still null

Comment: change var filesObj = []; to var filesObj = {};  You may or may not need the stringify function when you do try it both with or without.

Comment: then i cant use `.push()`. what should i use instead?

Comment: Actually, { 'name': name } takes care of the {} thing, so let's back up.  [{"name":"delete-icon.png"},{"name":"anothersomething.exe"},{"name":"something.‌​exe"}] should be parsed.  That's a key value pair, so on your controller key is a string & value is a string, so public ActionResult ImportCommit(KeyValuePair<string, string> filenames) or Dictionary<string, string>.

Comment: Setting it to a KeyValuePair also didnt work. For some reason I feel like what I am posting is not getting through to my controller... Any ideas there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to modify my `AJAX` to `POST` like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/dat/Controller",
    data: JSON.stringify(filesObj),
    contentType: "application/json",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log("Success: " + result);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        console.log("Error: " + result);
    }
});
```

Changing `dataType` to `contentType` and adding `traditional: true` seemed to do the trick for me. The reason for this (I believe) is because the actual data that I was posting is technically not `JSON`. I added the `traditional: true` just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

The post data you send via the data field of the ajax method needs to be name value pairs.  Asp.Net will map them in the Request Params collection via their name. E.g. if you post an object like this,

```
{
    fileNames: JSON.stringify(arFileNames)
};
```

It can then be accessed server side via,

```
string json = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["fileNames"];
```

If your json looks something like this,

```
"{"filenames":["somefile","somefile2","somefile3"]}"
```

You could use newtonsoft JSON ([JSON.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)) to convert it to a list of strings by creatong a class to represent it, like this,

```
public class JsonResultFileNames 
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "filenames")]
    public string[] FileNames { get; set; }        
}
```

Then convert the json to JsonResultFileNames with,

```
JsonResultFileNames jsonResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResultFileNames>(jsonStringHere);
```

Then you have a c# object representing your json data.  Also you can get way more complex with this, but the important thing to note with JSON.Net, is it quite literally deserializes into a c# representation.  E.g. if you want to deserialize straight to a string array, then there should only be an array of strings in your json (no object/field names etc).

E.g. where I work we have an api that returns results like this,

{
       status: {
           success: true;
       },
       customerdata {
         id: {some-guid},
         name: Some Customer Name
       }
   }

The problem with that, is my C# class needs to be composed of nested classes, e.g. I need a class to represent status and a class to represent customerdata.  Things can get weird naming wise when doing that, I ended up with things like CustomerResponse, CustomerResponseStatus, CustomerResponseData, where CustomerResponseStatus and CustomerResponseData are exposed in CustomerRespnose, and I deserialize the json to the CustomerResponse type.

If your json is just an array of strings, you should be able to use string[] for the type passed into JsonConvert.Deserialize, which would not require you to make response classes to hold the data.